# Spinner color is gray on white = invisible:(

Tags: android

I'm using default spinner

```
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner)).setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

How come elements are on a white background and a foreground color gray? It seems strange to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you set it with `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`.

You can write your own Adapter class:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
spinner.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(CLASS.this, R.layout.spinner_layout, spinnerAdapter));
```

Then it will look like the way you design in `spinner_layout`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, and this may help others comes here for answers.
Basically, it is because of the use of application context here. If you use the application context, the base theme will be applied on your layout and not the theme of your activity and that is the reason the color is white.

The details are well explained in the link: [spinner text color is white?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279925/spinner-text-color-is-white) and [here](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/)

Thanks [commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) for providing the answer to the original question.