# spinner text color is white?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I use a Spinner inside a layout.
I use this code:

```
...
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spin_prod_promo" />
...
```

Now, when I assign it's adapter I use this code:

```
...
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mcontext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mylabels);
 // Drop down layout style
 dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 Spinner myspinner = (Spinner) V.findViewById(R.id.spin_prod_promo);
 // attaching data adapter to spinner
 myspinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
...
```

My problem is that, the text color of the spinner is white... thus unreadable, and I do not set it to be this way anywhere in the code.

The "funny thing" is that I use the exact same code in a different activity and the Spinner has the right colors.
The difference is that in this (BAD) case the spinner is located in a fragment.

- So if the spinner is in an activity - colors are fine
- If the spinner is located on a fragment - color is messed up

I tried using a custom layout for the items of the spinner, but all I succeeded was to make the spinner look disabled. Plus there is always an item in the dropdown that has the color of the background (it can only be seen if I click on it, then I can see the content as long as I keep the click on)
What is going on here?
How can I solve this problem?

Is there something I can do to set the colors of the spinner to be the colors of the theme?
All other widgets in the fragment have normal colors...

Thank you

Comment: What is `mcontext`? If it is not the activity that is hosting the fragment, that's probably your problem.

Comment: Context mcontext = getActivity().getApplicationContext(); Is this wrong?

Comment: When I changed the layout of the item to a custom layout and I set the color of the TextView to black, it appears to be having effect. But this is annoying... Why is it happening? (so my problem is solved)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Context mcontext = getActivity().getApplicationContext(); Is this wrong?

Yes, this is wrong. Only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know **exactly why** you are using `getApplicationContext()`. In particular, never use `getApplicationContext()` for inflating layouts, as [it will screw things up by not using the right theme](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/).

I would delete `mcontext` entirely, replacing it with `getActivity()` where needed in your fragment.

Comment: Thanks, I already discovered that you were right in the first place :) That's why I placed the second "Answer". So thanks again, your expertise is very welcome. Even if my first solution works too... it is not clean, that is why I accepted yours. It's a lot better your way

Comment: Everyday I learn something new. I love this. Thank you (I learn Android by example and code  _(not the best way)_ so your explanations are very helping)

Comment: Strange behavior from android sdk, but 1 million upvotes from me, this issue was blowing my mind up.

Answer (score 6):

just try this..

```
String[]array={"A","B","C","D"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>  (**YourClassName.this**,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,array);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**NOTE** `YourClassName.this`  is your current class name.This code is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It is to declare a custom layout for the item of the Spinner and use it instead of the default one. And in the custom layout, I set the color of the TextView text to black.
It works this way.
So the code: (promospin_row.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/tv_promo_txt"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the java code:

```
  // Creating adapter for spinner
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mcontext, R.layout.promospin_row, R.id.tv_promo_txt, mylabels);
  // Drop down layout style
  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.promospin_row);
  Spinner myspinner = (Spinner) V.findViewById(R.id.spin_prod_promo);
  // attaching data adapter to spinner
  myspinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

This way, the item text becomes black. And no other anomalies.
Thank you @CommonsWare for your time

Comment: "mylabels" above can be retrieved using : final String[] mylabels = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.one_list);

Answer (score 2):

Just use null instead of getApplicationContext().
It must work.
I have tried it and its working.
In your Application you can use null instead of mcontext

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too. This is not a solution but a potential workaround for others to try in case the above solutions don't work.

Set the background color of the popup that appears when the spinner is selected to something that contrasts the white text color.

```
<Spinner
    ...
    android:popupBackground="@color/layout_background"
    ... />
```

Here I have defined layout_background as a dark greyish color #565656 in a seperate file called colors.xml located in my src/main/java/res/values folder.

Comment: UPVOTE, Unless this doesn't answer the OP question, but it can no doubt be a solution to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to indeed use `GetApplication()` as the context instead of

`getActivity().getApplicationContext();`

This way I can use the default item layout without having to declare a new custom layout.

So I guess, CommonsWare was right afterall. It is the context that blew things up.
Please @Commonsware, make your comment an answer so I can accept it, because you deserve it.

**EDIT**

*I was writing this while you wrote your answer, that is why it seems I didn't see your answer* :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use getBaseContext() instead of mcontext.
Worked for me. I set the adapter of spinner inside onItemClick function of AutoCompleteTextView and had the same problem of text color until I used getBaseContext(). Hope this answer helps.